# await for mapping array before using data without settimeout

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, promise

I'm using angular 13.
I have an array where I use a map() .. my problem is that the array is used in reloadDatasource() before mapping it. I'm looking for a way to await for map() finished before passing data to the function reloadDatasource.

this is my code :

```
  CheckAllChangeClick(event: any) {
this.myArray = this.myArray.map((x: any) => ({ ...x, selected: event.target.checked }));
this.mySelectedItemsCounter = this.myArray.filter((x: any) => x.selected == true).length;
this.reloadDatasource(this.myArray);
```

}

please notice that when I'm using setTimeOut() inside the function this.reloadDatasource everything is going well.

```
  reloadDatasource(bufferIndexItems: any) {
console.log('buff  : ', bufferIndexItems);
this.filtredIndexItems = [];
setTimeout(() => {
this.filtredIndexItems = bufferIndexItems;
}, 100);
```

}

but setTimeOut() is still a wrong solution .. I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Your code doesn't look asynchronous at all so your three lines should run consecutive.

Comment: but it is not .. when i console this.myArray it seems to me that the property ( selected ) is not added !!

Comment: Simple example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC7gBcACAWwE8BBVVZcgLmIG8BfAbQF1iBeYzvXADMQGIsQCWPYgAZsE4gB5iARlkSA1Osy5iuslRp14ABwCuEABbom4gCaNxLHPkGmwwQuPDFjqcWEJ0NABzRmQwckwmHT1QSBgEaBBgoNRg5xYXNw8vMGJkY2NYMFsABVQQYyxmGN0KalpyKXrDcnhSAvQADx4APmJreCGugBpiCFg4D1h7YkFkaAmnDPxff0CWxucCopLyyqw8NYD0TbpnXSA

Comment: Not async at all. The code you show isn't async at all either. One thing to note is that if you console.log an object you don't log a snapshot, but a reference, so it can change even after the log.